# Does the set of all piecewise constant functions form a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A function $f\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is piecewise constant if and only if it is a constant function $x\to c$ or there exist $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n$ and $c_0,...,c_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f: x\to \begin{cases}
c_0 & x<a_1\\
c_i & a_i\leq x < a_{i+1}\\
c_n & a_n\leq x
\end{cases}$$

where $1\leq i \leq n$. Does the set of all piecewise constant functions form a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

I've been stuck on this one for a bit. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it does - see [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/linear-algebra-set-of-piecewise-continuous-functions-is-a-vector-space.666820/) (constant functions are continuous).

Comment: Recall that showing a subset is a subspace requires less verification than showing it is a vector space "from scratch".  If you know $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space (of functions), then showing a nonempty subset is a subspace comes down to showing "closure" under a few "operations" (including the identity element, a "nullary" operation).

Comment: The inequalities in your definition are off--you probably want the middle one to be $a_i\leq x<a_{i+1}$.  If both sides are $\leq$, then this forces $f(a_{i+1})$ to be equal to both $c_i$ and $c_{i+1}$.

Comment: You're right, thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, this definition is not what most people would call "piecewise constant"; the usual definition would have strict inequalities everywhere.

Comment: Also, why not split it by $x\le a_1,$ $a_i<x\le a_{i+1}$ and $a_n<x$? It might be better to say that there are pairwise disjoint intervals $I_0,...,I_n$ such that $I_0\cup\cdots\cup I_n=\Bbb R,$ $I_0$ has no lower endpoint, $I_n$ has no upper endpoint, and for $1\le k\le n$ we have that $a_k$ is the upper endpoint of $I_{k-1}$ and the lower endpoint of $I_k.$ Then we can define $f(x)=c_k$ for $x\in I_k.$ It's certainly more complicated-seeming, I admit, but it doesn't actually make things that much more difficult.

Comment: I imagine the question was composed with closed-on-the-left, open-on-the-right intervals specifically to remove, for the homework-doer, the technicalities associated with a more "natural" definition.

Comment: One approach would be as follows: show that a function is piecewise constant (according to this definition) if and only if it has finitely many discontinuities and, for every $x\in\Bbb R$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(y)=f(x)$ for all $y\in[x,x+\delta)$. With this characterization, it's quite easy to show that the sum of two piecewise constant functions is piecewise constant. (But proving this characterization probably goes a little bit outside the scope of the course this problem came from.)

Answer (score 2):

The hard part of this is showing that a sum of piecewise constant functions is piecewise constant.  Suppose $f$ and $g$ are piecewise constant, with the pieces for $f$ being given by the numbers $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_n$ and the pieces for $g$ being given by the numbers $a_1'<a_2'<\dots<a_m'$.  Let $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_N$ be all of the numbers $\{a_1,\dots,a_n,a_1',\dots,a_m'\}$ put in order (probably $N=n+m$, but it might be smaller if $a_i=a_j'$ for some $i,j$).  Can you prove that $f+g$ is piecewise constant with the pieces given by these numbers $b_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Every function you describe is a linear combination of characteristic functions
$$
           \chi_{(-\infty,a)},\chi_{[a,b)},\chi_{[b,\infty)},
$$
where $\chi_{E}(s)=1$ if $s \in E$ and is $0$ if $s \notin E$. It may be easier for you to work with such functions because, for example, the following is a way to decompose into common partition:
\begin{align}
     A\chi_{[a,b)}+B\chi_{[c,d)} & =A\chi_{[a,b)}(\chi_{(-\infty,c]}+\chi_{[c,d)}+\chi_{[d,\infty)}) \\
      & +B(\chi_{(-\infty,a)}+\chi_{[a,b)}+\chi_{[b,\infty)})\chi_{[c,d)}.
\end{align}
Any of the products is another one of the 3 basic types, or is $0$.